# Why so repetitive in davening?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, temple-service-avoda

Looking at a [siddur](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Preparatory_Prayers%2C_Korbanot%2C_Order_of_the_Temple_Service_(Ana_Bekoach)?lang=en), in the Korbanos, the order of the Temple service is written. In the first paragraph (אַבַּיֵּי הֲוָה מְסַדֵּר), it lists everything that is done in a strange manner, it says what one action is and what it is before, and then what that second action is and what it comes before. Why is it listed in this manner, wouldn't it make more sense to say first was this, then this, then this, etc.?

Comment: The title is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive source for my answer, but I believe it is correct.

The passage to which you refer from the siddur is actually a direct quote from the [gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.33a?lang=he).

So your question is really on the gemara- why did the gemara choose to use that language intead of writing it more simply?

I believe the answer is based on the whole context. The gemara is discussing which services in the Beis Hamikdosh came first. So it makes sense that this source is also written in the same way- while discussing the order of the day, it describes each step in relation to what comes before it.

Right after this section of the gemara, the gemara continues by trying to prove each point- how do we know that X is before Y?

So while I didn't see any commentator say this explicitly (though I checked!), I think this is the explanation.

Comment: If so, why does it switch halfway through to not saying it that way?